# In R how to remove all columns of a matrix that contain a negative number?

Tags: r, matrix, dimensions, identity-column

I want to remove those columns from a matrix `M` that contain at least one negative number. For example, if

```
M = (1  0  0  1)
    (1 -1  0  2)
    (2  3  4 -3)
```

I want M to become

```
M = (1  0)
    (1  0)
    (2  4)
```

**How to type** `M <- removeNegativeColumns(M)` **code?**

Answer (score 6):

Simple way could be using sum for column for condition where `value < 0 (-ve)`.

```
    # Data
    M <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1,1, -1,  0,  2,2,  3,  4, -3), ncol = 4, byrow = T)

    M[, !colSums(M < 0 )]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    0
#[2,]    1    0
#[3,]    2    4
```

Comment: I can't beat this for speed.

Comment: to win a few characters: `M[,!colSums(M < 0 )]`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Updated answer considering your suggestion. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
M <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1,1, -1,  0,  2,2,  3,  4, -3), ncol = 4, byrow = T)

M1<- apply(M, 2,function(i)
{
  p<- any(i <0)==FALSE #(any(as.vector(i)) < 0)
  p
})

M<- M[,M1]
```

Comment: `any(i <0)==FALSE` is the same as `!any(i<0)` or `all(i>=0)`

Answer (score 1):

```
removeNegativeColumns <- function(M) M[,apply(M>=0,2,all)]
removeNegativeColumns(M)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    0
# [2,]    1    0
# [3,]    2    4
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the minimum of each row is less than zero, then use that to filter your matrix:

```
filter <- apply(M, 2, function (x) min(x) < 0)
M <- M[,!filter]
```

Edit:
As per Moody_Mudskipper this is a similar but superior (and correct) method:

```
filter <- apply(data, 2, function (x) any(x < 0))
data <- data[,!filter]
```

Comment: `any` will be a bit faster than min, and you can replace `filter ==T` by just `filter`, but here you need to filter columns and remove thos so it'd be `M[,!filter]`

Comment: I like this solution, but `argument x is of class numeric, should be a matrix`, how do you fix that?

Comment: the problem I am trying to solve is a bit different: `function(x) colIQRs(x, na.rm = TRUE) < 1.6` is the actual predicate I am looking for

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought if I post a simpler question, from the given answers I would realise the solution to my problem, but that does not seem to be the case :-)